# Order PHP array according to specific field names

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sorting

```
Array
(
[0] =Array
    (
        [id] =3
        [title] =Tst topic 111 main
        [created] =2012-11-06 13:04:57
        [sticked] = 
        [forums_id] =1
        [status] =open
    )

[1] =Array
    (
        [id] =6
        [title] =Topic 222 Main
        [created] =2012-11-04 15:31:15
        [sticked] = 
        [forums_id] =1
        [status] =open
    )

[2] =Array
    (
        [id] =7
        [title] =dfgdfgdfg
        [created] =2012-11-19 13:27:10
        [sticked] =
        [forums_id] =1
        [status] =open
    )

[3] =Array
    (
        [id] =9
        [title] =sdf ertert ertwer
        [created] =2012-11-20 11:30:55
        [sticked] =2012-11-20 11:30:00
        [forums_id] =1
        [status] =&close
    )

[4] =Array
    (
        [id] =10
        [title] =345245
        [created] =2012-11-20 11:34:17
        [sticked] =2012-11-20 11:34:00
        [forums_id] =&1
        [status] =open
    )

)
```

This is my result multi-dimensional array. In which some topics have `sticked` fields with datetime stamp. I want to order this array first with `sticked` field (DESC order) then all sticked topics will be at top of the array. Then i want to order all arrays which having null sticked field in DESC order with their `created` field.
 Is it possible ?
The order i am expecting is `[4] - [3] - [2] - [0] - [1]`.

Comment: yes its possible. What have you tried ?

Comment: @Quasarthespacething  I am a starter in php. No idea. please help me.

Comment: It's possible using usort http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php Probably two usorts. Be brave and give it a try first ;)

Comment: from where you are getting this array, it may be possible to easily sort them at its source

Comment: In the future, please post your variables using [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php), in stead of `print_r()`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this page :

PHP Array sorting functions

http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score -1):

Only add this line to your code

```
$final=arsort($yourarray);
print_r($final);
```

Or you can see help at [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php)

May it helpful!!